# winpcapy errors when moving from python 3.5.2 to python 3.7.4

Tags: python, windows, winpcap

I've been happily using some python to generate raw Ethernet frames and sending them out an interface of choice on Windows 7 using Python 3.5.2 with winpcapy. I've just installed Python 3.7.4 and now receive an error when trying to run the same code.

```
import ctypes
import winpcapy
import sys

errbuf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(winpcapy.PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE)

alldevs = ctypes.POINTER(winpcapy.pcap_if_t)()
winpcapy.pcap_findalldevs(ctypes.byref(alldevs), errbuf)
device = alldevs.contents
interfaces = []
while True:
    interfaces.append(device)
    if not device.next:
        break
    device = device.next.contents
print(interfaces)
```

The code snippet when run in 3.5 prints a list of the interfaces found. However if I run it in 3.7 I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "Z:\proj\eth\socket.py", line 5, in 
<module> errbuf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(winpcapy.PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE) 
AttributeError: module 'winpcapy' has no attribute 'PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE'
```

Now, I could replace 'PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE' with an integer value but then I get further issues which looks like there's something generally wrong with how i'm using winpcapy in 3.7. Has anyone else hit these sort of issues?

Comment: Show us the **full** error traceback.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "Z:\proj\eth\socket.py", line 5, in <module>
        errbuf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(winpcapy.PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE)
    AttributeError: module 'winpcapy' has no attribute 'PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE'

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question itself. Code blocks and stack traces are not readable in comments. Also the first thing I noticed: if you name your module `socket` it might clash with the built-in module `socket`.

Comment: Done. I take your point on naming a file 'socket'. It was just a temporary file as I had plucked the portion of code from a larger file to test what I was posting worked (or not) in isolation. The original file gives the same error but I didn't want to post the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you obtain `winpcapy`?

The [PyPI winpcapy package](https://pypi.org/project/WinPcapy/) is not the same as the [historical winpcapy script](https://code.google.com/archive/p/winpcapy/) that was on Google Code. The PyPI package exposes the `libpcap` API in the `winpcapy.winpcapy_types` module.

In the original `winpcapy` script `PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE` was a value defined in the `winpcapy` module. You could import it just like in the code you provided:

```
import winpcapy
print(winpcapy.PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE)
```

However, in the newer PyPI package `PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE` is defined in `winpcapy.winpcapy_types`. So you would need to do something like:

```
from winpcapy import winpcapy_types as wtypes
print(wtypes.PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I originally got it from PyPI but it was a while ago. I've recently installed the latest winpcapy from PyPI though. Your second example works for me now in Python 3.7.4 (and the first one doesn't as expected). However, if I go back to Python 3.5.2 the first one works but the import of winpcapy_types fails in your second example. Thanks! Can't upvote as I don't have the rep!